# C# Core Library And Entity Framework 'admin' Equals 'Admin'

Tags: c#

[BE source code that using Equals function]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CoreAPI.Model.UserRoles.Users;

namespace CoreAPI.Repository.UserRoles.Users
{
    public class UserRepository : RepositoryImpl<User>, IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository() : base()
        {

        }

        public UserRepository(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {

        }

        public User FindByUserName(string userName)
        {
            return dbContext.Set<User>().Include("Roles.URRole").Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(userName)).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public IEnumerable<User> FindAll()
        {
            return dbContext.Set<User>().Include("Roles.URRole");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the submit json:
{
    "userName": "Admin",
    "passWord": "Admin@12345"
}

In Table Users, field UserName storing value "admin".I don't understand why the Equals function admit value "Admin" and "admin".
Please teach me what I missing.

Comment: I fixed my question.Used code only.

Answer (score 0):

The `Equals` here will be translated as equivalent SQL query by entity framework and the SQL adapter (same if you use `==`) .

In databases, there are different rules for comparing strings. This is what is called "*collation*". If the current collation of your database is Case Insensitive, then `Admin` and `admin` will be considered equal *by your database*.

This can be solved

1 - in your database, by changing collation of table, query or server, to a Case Sensitive one;

2 - or by pre-processing your input, depending on your actual requirements. (for instance, if you know you want to forbid all uppercase, it's easy to filter this before doing any query)

To precisely pinpoint a more precise answer for collation change, you need to provide your actual database system you are using (SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreeSQL? SQLite? etc..)

For instance, for SQL Server you can check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support